# code behind aspx page is not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a crystal report and attached to a button on aspx page. But code behind the button is not called at all. Please help.

axpx page Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Department Average Competency Rating" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/PageTemplate.master"
    CodeBehind="DepartmentAverageRating.aspx.vb" Inherits="PerformanceAppraisal.DepartmentAverageRating" %>

<%@ Register Src="Controls/EmployeeHeader.ascx" TagName="EmployeeHeader" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .ds_box
        {
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 32767;
        }
        .ds_tbl
        {
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
        .ds_head
        {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        .ds_subhead
        {
            background-color: #CCC;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            width: 32px;
        }
        .ds_cell
        {
            background-color: #EEE;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .ds_cell:hover
        {
            background-color: #F3F3F3;
        }
        /* This hover code won't work for IE */</style>
    <table class="ds_box" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ds_conclass" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td id="ds_calclass">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    &lt;script type="text/javascript">
        // <!-- <![CDATA[

        // Project: Dynamic Date Selector (DtTvB) - 2006-03-16
        // Script featured on JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com
        // Code begin...
        // Set the initial date.
        var ds_i_date = new Date();
        ds_c_month = ds_i_date.getMonth() + 1;
        ds_c_year = ds_i_date.getFullYear();

        // Get Element By Id
        function ds_getel(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        // Get the left and the top of the element.
        function ds_getleft(el) {
            var tmp = el.offsetLeft;
            el = el.offsetParent
            while (el) {
                tmp += el.offsetLeft;
                el = el.offsetParent;
            }
            return tmp;
        }
        function ds_gettop(el) {
            var tmp = el.offsetTop;
            el = el.offsetParent
            while (el) {
                tmp += el.offsetTop;
                el = el.offsetParent;
            }
            return tmp;
        }

        // Output Element
        var ds_oe = ds_getel('ds_calclass');
        // Container
        var ds_ce = ds_getel('ds_conclass');

        // Output Buffering
        var ds_ob = '';
        function ds_ob_clean() {
            ds_ob = '';
        }
        function ds_ob_flush() {
            ds_oe.innerHTML = ds_ob;
            ds_ob_clean();
        }
        function ds_echo(t) {
            ds_ob += t;
        }

        var ds_element; // Text Element...

        var ds_monthnames = [
'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
]; // You can translate it for your language.

        var ds_daynames = [
'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'
]; // You can translate it for your language.

        // Calendar template
        function ds_template_main_above(t) {
            return '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="ds_tbl">'
         + '<tr>'
         + '<td class="ds_head" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ds_py();"><<</td>'
         + '<td class="ds_head" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ds_pm();"><</td>'
         + '<td class="ds_head" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ds_hi();" colspan="3">[Close]</td>'
         + '<td class="ds_head" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ds_nm();">></td>'
         + '<td class="ds_head" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ds_ny();">>></td>'
         + '</tr>'
         + '<tr>'
         + '<td colspan="7" class="ds_head">' + t + '</td>'
         + '</tr>'
         + '<tr>';
        }

        function ds_template_day_row(t) {
            return '<td class="ds_subhead">' + t + '</td>';
            // Define width in CSS, XHTML 1.0 Strict doesn't have width property for it.
        }

        function ds_template_new_week() {
            return '</tr><tr>';
        }

        function ds_template_blank_cell(colspan) {
            return '<td colspan="' + colspan + '"></td>'
        }

        function ds_template_day(d, m, y) {
            return '<td class="ds_cell" onclick="ds_onclick(' + d + ',' + m + ',' + y + ')">' + d + '</td>';
            // Define width the day row.
        }

        function ds_template_main_below() {
            return '</tr>'
         + '</table>';
        }

        // This one draws calendar...
        function ds_draw_calendar(m, y) {
            // First clean the output buffer.
            ds_ob_clean();
            // Here we go, do the header
            ds_echo(ds_template_main_above(ds_monthnames[m - 1] + ' ' + y));
            for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                ds_echo(ds_template_day_row(ds_daynames[i]));
            }
            // Make a date object.
            var ds_dc_date = new Date();
            ds_dc_date.setMonth(m - 1);
            ds_dc_date.setFullYear(y);
            ds_dc_date.setDate(1);
            if (m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 10 || m == 12) {
                days = 31;
            } else if (m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) {
                days = 30;
            } else {
                days = (y % 4 == 0) ? 29 : 28;
            }
            var first_day = ds_dc_date.getDay();
            var first_loop = 1;
            // Start the first week
            ds_echo(ds_template_new_week());
            // If sunday is not the first day of the month, make a blank cell...
            if (first_day != 0) {
                ds_echo(ds_template_blank_cell(first_day));
            }
            var j = first_day;
            for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {
                // Today is sunday, make a new week.
                // If this sunday is the first day of the month,
                // we've made a new row for you already.
                if (j == 0 && !first_loop) {
                    // New week!!
                    ds_echo(ds_template_new_week());
                }
                // Make a row of that day!
                ds_echo(ds_template_day(i + 1, m, y));
                // This is not first loop anymore...
                first_loop = 0;
                // What is the next day?
                j++;
                j %= 7;
            }
            // Do the footer
            ds_echo(ds_template_main_below());
            // And let's display..
            ds_ob_flush();
            // Scroll it into view.
            ds_ce.scrollIntoView();
        }

        // A function to show the calendar.
        // When user click on the date, it will set the content of t.
        function ds_sh(t) {
            // Set the element to set...
            ds_element = t;
            // Make a new date, and set the current month and year.
            var ds_sh_date = new Date();
            ds_c_month = ds_sh_date.getMonth() + 1;
            ds_c_year = ds_sh_date.getFullYear();
            // Draw the calendar
            ds_draw_calendar(ds_c_month, ds_c_year);
            // To change the position properly, we must show it first.
            ds_ce.style.display = '';
            // Move the calendar container!
            the_left = ds_getleft(t);
            the_top = ds_gettop(t) + t.offsetHeight;
            ds_ce.style.left = the_left + 'px';
            ds_ce.style.top = the_top + 'px';
            // Scroll it into view.
            ds_ce.scrollIntoView();
        }

        // Hide the calendar.
        function ds_hi() {
            ds_ce.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Moves to the next month...
        function ds_nm() {
            // Increase the current month.
            ds_c_month++;
            // We have passed December, let's go to the next year.
            // Increase the current year, and set the current month to January.
            if (ds_c_month > 12) {
                ds_c_month = 1;
                ds_c_year++;
            }
            // Redraw the calendar.
            ds_draw_calendar(ds_c_month, ds_c_year);
        }

        // Moves to the previous month...
        function ds_pm() {
            ds_c_month = ds_c_month - 1; // Can't use dash-dash here, it will make the page invalid.
            // We have passed January, let's go back to the previous year.
            // Decrease the current year, and set the current month to December.
            if (ds_c_month < 1) {
                ds_c_month = 12;
                ds_c_year = ds_c_year - 1; // Can't use dash-dash here, it will make the page invalid.
            }
            // Redraw the calendar.
            ds_draw_calendar(ds_c_month, ds_c_year);
        }

        // Moves to the next year...
        function ds_ny() {
            // Increase the current year.
            ds_c_year++;
            // Redraw the calendar.
            ds_draw_calendar(ds_c_month, ds_c_year);
        }

        // Moves to the previous year...
        function ds_py() {
            // Decrease the current year.
            ds_c_year = ds_c_year - 1; // Can't use dash-dash here, it will make the page invalid.
            // Redraw the calendar.
            ds_draw_calendar(ds_c_month, ds_c_year);
        }

        // Format the date to output.
        function ds_format_date(d, m, y) {
            // 2 digits month.
            m2 = '00' + m;
            m2 = m2.substr(m2.length - 2);
            // 2 digits day.
            d2 = '00' + d;
            d2 = d2.substr(d2.length - 2);
            // YYYY-MM-DD
            return m2 + '/' + d2 + '/' + y;
        }

        // When the user clicks the day.
        function ds_onclick(d, m, y) {
            // Hide the calendar.
            ds_hi();
            // Set the value of it, if we can.
            if (typeof (ds_element.value) != 'undefined') {
                ds_element.value = ds_format_date(d, m, y);
                // Maybe we want to set the HTML in it.
            } else if (typeof (ds_element.innerHTML) != 'undefined') {
                ds_element.innerHTML = ds_format_date(d, m, y);
                // I don't know how should we display it, just alert it to user.
            } else {
                alert(ds_format_date(d, m, y));
            }
        }

        // And here is the end.

        // ]]> -->
    &lt;/script>

    <table width="80%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr class="rule" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <b><u>Enter a Date Range</u></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr class="rule" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Start Date:</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="requiredControl" onclick="ds_sh(this);"
                    ReadOnly="False" Style="cursor: text"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valReqdStartDate" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate"
                    ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" CssClass="warning" runat="server" Text="*" />
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="valStartDateValid" runat="server" CssClass="warning" ErrorMessage="The value must be in proper date form (MM/DD/YYYY)"
                    ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" Text="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>End Date:</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="requiredControl" onclick="ds_sh(this);"
                    ReadOnly="False" Style="cursor: text"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate"
                    ErrorMessage="End Date is required" CssClass="warning" runat="server" Text="*" />
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="valEndDateValid" runat="server" CssClass="warning" ErrorMessage="The value must be in proper date form (MM/DD/YYYY)"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" Text="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="2">
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="warning"
                    HeaderText="The following errors were found with this review:" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <b>Report Format:</b>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportFormat" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="PDF" Value="PDF" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="EXCEL" Value="EXCEL"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ViewReport" runat="server">
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CssClass="buttonStyle" Text="View Report" />
            </td>     
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

---

Code behind the page:

```
Partial Public Class DepartmentAverageRating
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Private _employee As Employee

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("AppraisalId") = -1
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            'If (Security.UserRole <> UserRole.Manager Or Security.UserRole <> UserRole.Supervisor) AndAlso Not Utility.UserIsHr Then
            '    Response.Redirect("EmployeeSummary.aspx")
            'End If
            '_employee = New Employee(Security.CurrentEmployee)
            txtStartDate.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            'Launch the report with the appropriate parameters.
            Dim strReportUrl As String

            strReportUrl = "ShowReport.ashx?Type=DepartmentAverageRating.rpt&StartDate=" & txtStartDate.Text & "&EndDate=" & txtEndDate.Text & "&Format=" & ddlReportFormat.SelectedValue

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "OpenWin", _
                   "&lt;script>window.open('" & strReportUrl & "')&lt;/script>", False)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no click handler on the button in the markup. Try:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CssClass="buttonStyle" OnClick="btnView_Click" Text="View Report" />
```

Comment: Yes, the code for the handler is in the code behind... But you have to wire it up in the UI for it to be called when the button is clicked. Simply add OnClick attribute to the button: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx shows adding the button click handler in both .aspx page and code behind (though doing only one is necessary).